# Edit Classes-Registry of other users

Tags: registry

I know how to edit the registry of other users. I load the hive into regedit and than change the values I want.

```
reg load HKU\test C:\Users\TestUser\ntuser.dat
```

This is no problem at all. But I noticed that there are not all values displayed that would need to be in HKEY_Current_User

I want to edit the settings in HKEY_Current_User\SOFTWARE\Classes
Everywhere in the internet it says that the ntuser.dat is the HKEY_CURRENT_USER key of the other user. But there is no "Classes" entry in that hive.

So how do I edit those settings using the Registry Editor?
Or is there any other possible way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer:
The Classes Key is outsourced and can be found here:

```
C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat
```

Where TestUser is the username of the user.
Load and edit as descibed in the question.